# Is it possible to create a virtual iterator class?

Tags: c++, iterator, virtual

I have a virtual container "ISequence" which is used as a template for container implementations on arrays or lists. I have implemented an iterator for both Array and List containers. What I want to do is to create a virtual IIterator class so I can create algorithms that use iterators and accept ISequence is a parameter. My goal is to be free of implementation.

I tried adding virtual IIterator class to ISequence with no methods and that inherits std::iterator but that didn't work

ISequence class:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class ISequence {
protected:
    int length; //length of sequence
public:
    virtual int getLength() const = 0; //get length of sequence
    virtual bool getIsEmpty() const = 0; //check if empty
public:
    virtual T get(int index) const = 0; //get item based on index
    virtual T getFirst() const = 0; //get first item
    virtual T getLast() const = 0; //get last item
    virtual ISequence<T>* getSubSequence(int startIndex, int endIndex) const = 0;
    virtual void append(T item) = 0; //add item to the end
    virtual void prepend(T item) = 0; //add item to the beginning
    virtual void insertAt(int index, T item) = 0; //insert item at a specific point
    virtual void remove(T item) = 0; //remove specific item
    virtual void replace(int index, T item) = 0; //replace an item
};
```

Array with an iterator:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class ArraySequence: public ISequence<T> {
private:
    T* data;
public:
    ArraySequence();
    ArraySequence(ISequence<T>* sequence);
    ArraySequence(int n, int leftLimit, int rightLimit);
    ArraySequence<T>& operator=(const ArraySequence<T>& sequence);
    ~ArraySequence();
public:
    virtual int getLength() const override;
    virtual bool getIsEmpty() const override;
public:
    virtual T get(int index) const override;
    virtual T getFirst() const override;
    virtual T getLast() const override;
    virtual ArraySequence<T>* getSubSequence(int startIndex, int endIndex) const override;
    virtual void append(T item) override;
    virtual void prepend(T item) override;
    virtual void insertAt(int index, T item) override;
    virtual void remove(T item) override;
    virtual void replace(int index, T item) override;
private:
    class MyIterator: public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T> {
        friend class ArraySequence;
    private:
        T* pos;
        MyIterator(T* pos);
    public:
        MyIterator(const MyIterator &it);
        ~MyIterator();
    public:
        typename MyIterator::reference operator*() const;
        typename MyIterator::pointer operator->() const;
        typename MyIterator::reference operator[](const typename MyIterator::difference_type& n) const;
        typename MyIterator::difference_type operator-(const MyIterator& it) const;
        MyIterator operator++(int);
        MyIterator& operator++();
        MyIterator operator--(int);
        MyIterator& operator--();
        MyIterator operator+(const typename MyIterator::difference_type& n) const;
        MyIterator& operator+=(const typename MyIterator::difference_type& n);
        MyIterator operator-(const typename MyIterator::difference_type& n) const;
        MyIterator& operator-=(const typename MyIterator::difference_type& n);
        bool operator!=(const MyIterator& it) const;
        bool operator==(const MyIterator& it) const;
        bool operator<(const MyIterator& it) const;
        bool operator>(const MyIterator& it) const;
        bool operator<=(const MyIterator& it) const;
        bool operator>=(const MyIterator& it) const;
    };
public:
    typedef MyIterator iterator;
    typedef MyIterator const const_iterator;
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;
};
```

My code for abstract IIterator (as an addition to ISequence):

```cpp
protected:
    class IIterator: public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T> { //virtual Iterator class
    };
public:
    typedef IIterator iterator;
    typedef IIterator const const_iterator;
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;
```

Then I inherit it by MyIterator in Array.

With what I tried I get the "Invalid operands to binary expression ('ISequence::IIterator' and 'ISequence::IIterator')" error message when I run simple forrange cycle.

Comment: You did not provide the exact context but I suspect this was due to missing comparison operators for `IIterator`. As a side note, you probably might want to reconsider defining `const_iterator` as `const` type.

Comment: Standard library (STL) make it different way. <algorithm> header have a generic algorithms like [for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each), [remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) etc. which works on any iterator.

Comment: To answer the headline question, yes. That's exactly what `std::iterator` does.

Comment: @sweenish `std::iterator` is not virtual

Comment: Why are you doing this? I'm not convinced at all that any of this is needed to do whatever you have in mind. On that note: please share what you're really trying to achieve. Show the code you have in mind that will be using it. It's a good bet that that code can be made to work in C++ without doing any of what you propose, and it will read not all that different from C# (or Python).

Comment: @fdan "std::iterator is the base class provided to simplify definitions of the required types for iterators" from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator

Comment: @fdan It took looking at the <iterator> files, but it appears to not be; I misunderstood what cppreference.com was saying. I'm still a bit surprised, though.

Comment: @KubaOber it was my homework and I needed to make sorting algorithms for ISequence so it works on Array, List, etc. My goal right now is to make those algorithms work on iterators. Sort functions signature ```c++ void quickSort(ISequence<T>* seq, int start, int end, C cmp); ``` where C cmp is a compare function. Maybe I need to give up making MyIterator class member of Array and make it external? Or make std::iterator a parameter? Or the best solution here is to add 2 other template types?

Comment: You don't need an `ISequence`. You would in C# if you had no `IList` etc. Not in C++. Seriously. Get rid of that, and wherever you accept `ISequence`, accept a generic type. And it will still work, as long as the concrete types you pass along indeed act like they should. For example, `getIsEmpty` would be a C++ equivalent of an extension method, i.e. a freestanding function, not a member: `template <class C> bool isEmpty(const C& sequence) { return sequence.begin() == sequence.end(); }`. Your framework would look at home in C#, but not in C++.

Comment: In C++, someone seeing a "sequence" with no iterators will be just confused. There's no need for it. Whatever cool sequences you have, just make sure they provide `begin()` and `end()` members, or that there are `std::begin` and `std::end` overloads for them. That automatically makes them iterable. If this "framework" was given to you by a teacher for a C++ class, then the teacher just doesn't know C++, and I'm not joking: they are unfamiliar with the basic idioms and patterns of C++, never mind the standard library. C# is not C++. You're taught C# in this class, and the cake is a total lie.

Comment: @KubaOber that's how higher education in IT works in Russia. Maybe there are good sources or literature to learn C++ in a good way?

Answer (score 1):

The concepts you're implementing are rather foundational in C#. Perhaps there's a good reason none of that exists in C++? Yes!

You are trying to implement .Net library using C++. **This is not such a great idea**, since the design of that library caters to the limitations of C# and the CLR (or whatever they call it these days). C# can do much less with types at compile time, and it doesn't have a compile-time generic type substitution system like C++ does. By not using what C++ offers, you're reinventing the wheel and writing code that looks quite unidiomatic. And it'll likely be slower than it needs to be, since virtual method calls on iterators are liable to be invoked often, their overheads showing. The compiler will devirtualize some of the calls if it can, but that's not something to depend on.

Generalizing a bit; *The direct use of most any idiom from the .Net ecosystem in C++ is wrong by default unless proven otherwise*.

In C++ the notion of "interfaces" doesn't depend on virtual methods, but on concepts - i.e. constraints on types. There's no way to achieve this in C#, nor in CLR in general, the design doesn't support it. In C++, as long as the concrete type used fits within the constraints that the caller requires (e.g. is iterable), the compiler will take care of the rest. Idiomatically, you'd pass containers around either using [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) or iterators, and all code that accepts those should be generic: the type of the container or iterator should be a template parameter, and the iterators should not be forced to be of the same type - this was really a library design bug in older versions of C++ library.

So, the beauty of C++ is that you don't have to define any interfaces whatsoever. In C++20 you can constrain the types using concepts, but other than that, it's just simple - much simpler than in C#. The idea of ranges is to have objects that act "like" containers, i.e. you can iterate on them using range-for, but they aren't necessarily containers - they may be just a way to express a range of elements on a container, or even dynamically generated.

If you're thinking of doing this in support of porting code from C# to C++, then simply forget about the need for `ISequence` etc. Just use generic type parameters, optionally constrain them using concepts if you're using a C++20 compiler, and you're set. It's that easy. The container can be anything. Even the plain "C" array (shudder - don't use those, use `std::array` instead, always!).

Suppose we had following C# code:

```
System.IO.TextWriter cout = Console.Out;

Action<System.Collections.IEnumerable> printValues = (values) =>
{
    cout.WriteLine("printValues");
    foreach (var v in values)
        cout.Write($"{v} ");
    cout.Write("\n");
};

var list_of_ints = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var vector_of_strings = new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d"};
cout.WriteLine("* Entire containers");
printValues(list_of_ints);
printValues(vector_of_strings);
cout.WriteLine("\n* Subranges of containers");
printValues(list_of_ints.GetRange(1, list_of_ints.Count() - 1));
printValues(vector_of_strings.Take(vector_of_strings.Count() - 1));
```

Output:

```
* Entire containers
printValues
1 2 3 4 5
printValues
a b c d

* Subranges of containers
printValues
2 3 4 5
printValues
a b c
```

It wouldn't look much different in C++, as long as you stick to idiomatic C++ and don't try reimplementing .Net in C++:

```
#include <forward_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// This will accept entire containers, as well as C++20 ranges.
template <class C> void printValues(const C &values) {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " with container\n";
    for (auto &v : values)
        std::cout << v << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

// This is the more legacy way of doing it - to stay compatible with C++98 (shiver).
template <class I1, class I2> void printValues(I1 start, I2 end) {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " with iterators\n";
    for (; start != end; ++start)
        std::cout << *start << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::forward_list<int> list_of_ints{1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector<std::string> vector_of_strings{"a", "b", "c", "d"};

    std::cout << "* Entire containers\n";
    printValues(list_of_ints);
    printValues(vector_of_strings);
    std::cout << "\n* Subranges of containers\n";
    printValues(std::next(list_of_ints.cbegin()), list_of_ints.cend());
    printValues(vector_of_strings.cbegin(), std::prev(vector_of_strings.cend()));
}
```

Output:

```
* Entire containers
printValues with container
1 2 3 4 5 
printValues with container
a b c d 

* Subranges of containers
printValues with iterators
2 3 4 5 
printValues with iterators
a b c
```